# Additional characters in RC4 encryption

Tags: c++, qt, openssl, rc4-cipher

I am facing an issue when trying to encrypt a string using Open SSL RC4 function. Somme additionnal characters where added at the end of the encrypted string.

Here is my code :

```
RC4_KEY rc4_key;
QString key= "612c207468652066";

QByteArray keyData=key.QString::toUtf8();
unsigned char * mykey=reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(keyData.data());

QString input = "7447806cc997966f6b8b59a57c01bfe6fe8381d4fed5628b531fbeb1c4629151722ee712fa906dfea1c68b7015243bfcdd42d3e990c1bd6daa56df620a9d1e441f4ba308da5584e032f06fe925ee9df328fadab0ad2a5869fdea366189a397f72b320a4f11b0cc41cbfaa3b6923f20cc8c4c80d9c9b69eb5e2a6cc2fb9ee2e72ca79f08617b3b5812eddb3f58b68";
qDebug()<< "input"<<input << input.size();
QByteArray inputData=input.QString::toUtf8();
unsigned char * ciphertext1= (unsigned char*)malloc(input.size());
memset(ciphertext1, 0, input.size());
ciphertext1=reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(QByteArray::fromHex(inputData).data());
printf("ciphertext1: %s\n", ciphertext1);

RC4_set_key(&rc4_key,keyData.size() , mykey);

unsigned char * firsthashJson= (unsigned char*)malloc(input.size());
firsthashJson[input.size()-1]=0x00;
memset(firsthashJson, 0, input.size());
RC4(&rc4_key,input.length(),ciphertext1, firsthashJson);
printf("Decrypted: %s\n", firsthashJson);

QString str1 = QString::fromUtf8((char*)firsthashJson);
```

I obtained the following result: b036fe3eae7881fe135562335f9a##5265705250##b2a475f7a99cf400d34da436d522d9bc5566d8b7a015c7a16ee2d5e730199acf1f61fe2f3d6b9525e1c45acb36383253b4fc< Ú«Í`ã¿rßÖQÕ§ìj‗¤Ì&Öâ¤#>XÏ¸0õ+▲®╩Ä=╚líUm"ód☻Ô1ı┘©ÜLÔ»âH÷/o┐öñ▄|▄ÐÄ┤N  ☻§@ı2w5▒KTâUÆB¢ÏdÔxÚ⌂ê☺°¹╔«▓J)→8èê╔┤║ù@│k       ↕▬↨[║GtUË(♂D

the expected one is : b036fe3eae7881fe135562335f9a##5265705250##b2a475f7a99cf400d34da436d522d9bc5566d8b7a015c7a16ee2d5e730199acf1f61fe2f3d6b9525e1c45acb36383253b4fc

Do you have any idea of the source cause of this issue.

Thanks in advance for your help.

###############################################################

@paddy
Thank you for your help.

Unfortunately i have the same issue here is the new code:

```
RC4_KEY rc4_key;
QString key= "612c207468652066";

QByteArray keyData=key.QString::toUtf8();
unsigned char * mykey=reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(keyData.data());

QString input = "7447806cc997966f6b8b59a57c01bfe6fe8381d4fed5628b531fbeb1c4629151722ee712fa906dfea1c68b7015243bfcdd42d3e990c1bd6daa56df620a9d1e441f4ba308da5584e032f06fe925ee9df328fadab0ad2a5869fdea366189a397f72b320a4f11b0cc41cbfaa3b6923f20cc8c4c80d9c9b69eb5e2a6cc2fb9ee2e72ca79f08617b3b5812eddb3f58b68";
qDebug()<< "input"<<input << input.size();
QByteArray inputData=input.QString::toUtf8();
unsigned char * ciphertext1= (unsigned char*)malloc(input.size());
memset(ciphertext1, 0, input.size());
ciphertext1=reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(QByteArray::fromHex(inputData).data());
printf("ciphertext1: %s\n", ciphertext1);

RC4_set_key(&rc4_key,keyData.size() , mykey);

unsigned char * firsthashJson= (unsigned char*)malloc(input.size()+1);

memset(firsthashJson, 0, input.size()+1);
firsthashJson[input.size()]=0;

RC4(&rc4_key,input.size(),ciphertext1, firsthashJson);
printf("Decrypted: %s\n", firsthashJson);

firsthashJson[input.size()]=0;
QString str1 = QString::fromUtf8((char*)firsthashJson);

qDebug()<<"final string "<<str1<< str1.size();
```

Comment: You must allocate enough storage for your NUL-terminator, if you want NUL-terminated strings. This looks like a classic case of unterminated strings. It looks like you_tried_ with `firsthashJson[input.size()-1]=0x00;` but that's not the right position. Besides, you immediately clear the entire memory on the next line with `memset` so this one is pointless. You probably need `input.size() + 1` bytes, and to terminate you can then do `firsthashJson[input.size()] = 0;`. Consider doing that after the call to `RC4`.

Answer (score 0):

Your core problem is that you are passing `input.size()` as the `len` parameter to `RC4`, but `input.size()` is actually **double the size** of your `ciphertext1` because of hex encoding.

Here is a correct version without leaving the comfort and safety of Qt:

```
QString key = "612c207468652066";
QString input = "7447806cc997966f6b8b59a57c01bfe6fe8381d4fed5628b531fbeb1c4629151722ee712fa906dfea1c68b7015243bfcdd42d3e990c1bd6daa56df620a9d1e441f4ba308da5584e032f06fe925ee9df328fadab0ad2a5869fdea366189a397f72b320a4f11b0cc41cbfaa3b6923f20cc8c4c80d9c9b69eb5e2a6cc2fb9ee2e72ca79f08617b3b5812eddb3f58b68";

RC4_KEY rc4_key;
RC4_set_key(&rc4_key, key.size(), key.toUtf8().data()); // Or qUtf8Printable(key)
QByteArray ciphertext = QByteArray::fromHex(input.toUtf8());

QByteArray firsthashJson(ciphertext.size(), 0);
RC4(&rc4_key, ciphertext.size(), ciphertext.data(), firsthashJson.data());

QString decrypted = QString::fromUtf8(firsthashJson);
qDebug()<<"final string " << decrypted;
```